# How to show the color of polygons according to their some values using Google Maps Javascript API Data Layer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Could anybody give some guidance how to get that range bar and "coloring by one json property" feature appeared in the following video(1:28)?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwpmvI4vxNQ

I managed to use map.data.loadGeoJson, map.data.setStyle, map.data.addListener to show polygons and display values of properties of them on Google Maps.

Comment: What does your existing code look like? What does your GeoJSON look like?  Have you seen this [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-dynamic)?  Or [this one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to request the geoJSON first, because you must retrieve the min and max for the particular property by iterating of the features.

The bar may be a simple div with a CSS-gradient.

Then calculate in the style-function the percents for the current property-value.

The formula would be:

```
var pct = ((propertyValue-min)/(max-min));
```

Working with hsl-colors should be the easiest approach.

For the bar(e.g. gradient green>yellow>red ):

```
    background: linear-gradient(to right, 
                                hsl(120, 90%, 50%),
                                hsl(60, 90%, 50%),
                                hsl(0, 90%, 50%)) ;
```

the `fillColor` for the feature:

```
'hsl('+(120-(120*pct))+', 90%, 50%)'
```

Demo:(for points instead of polygons, but the workflow is the same, the calculated fillColor will be applied to marker-symbols)

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vxd0434s/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vxd0434s/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried the code in http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/vxd0434s/. Everything works but the bar. The bar doesn't appear. Do you know why?

Comment: You don't see the bar with the gradient in the fiddle? Which browser do you use?

Comment: I tried safari and chrome both don't work. Only a small white point at the middle top.

Comment: The rest of the demo is exactly what I need! Just this missing bar!

Comment: The white point should be the bar. Do you get any errors in the console?